# What does "s" mean inside of a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
def capital_indexes(string):

    indexes = []

    for i, s in enumerate(string):
        if s.isupper():
            indexes.append(1)
    return indexes
```

What does the `s` in the for loop mean?

Comment: It doesn't have any special meaning. It's just a variable. You can call it whatever you want. Do you mean to ask what [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) does in that loop?

Comment: How about [reading the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)? "...returns a tuple containing a count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from iterating over iterable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` is the index in the string, while `s` is a string of length 1 representing the letter at that index.

See documentation for enumerate